# How to enable back button on ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history, html5-history

I'm working on a site which navigates as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (!$('#ajax').length) { // Check if index.html was loaded. If not, navigate to index.html and load the hash part with ajax.
    document.location = document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
      + "#" + document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  }

  if (window.location.hash) // Check if the page is being loaded with a '#'. Load the file.
    $('#ajax').load(document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1));
});

$(document).on("click", "a:not(.regular)", function (e) {
  var url = this.href;
  if (url.indexOf("https") != -1 || url.indexOf('.html') == -1) // External link or picture
    return;

  e.preventDefault();

  $('#ajax').load(url, function () {
      document.location.href = '#' + url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  });
});

$(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
    // Back only!
    //location.reload();
    //$('#ajax').load(this.location);
});
```

The url changes when user navigates, even when user presses the back button. However, the page isn't refreshed when navigating back so only the url changes while the actual page remains the same.

How can I fix this? 
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7M6B/)** 
**[Actual site](http://www.test.florayuda.nl/)**

Comment: You mean you want the "back" button to force a page reload with the query string in the url?

Comment: Yes, or just a regular navigate to the url in the history. The `document.ready` code would fix the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the page identfier after the `#` is responsible for the effect. Everything behind `#` (URL fragment) is supposed to be interpreted by the browser locally. Thus, going back with the same URL but a different fragment does not trigger the browser to do a "reload", since he expects this to be a bookmark.

Change for a real parameter `.....?pageid=over_ons.html` or go with PATH_INFO `.../overons.html`

Besides that:

`document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`

is just

`document.location.hash`

Comment: `document.location.href =  '?' + url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '#' + url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);` Seems to do the job, thanks! But now the page twitches on each navigate. Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: The "twitches" are caused by the logo image. If all logos are in cache, it doesn't twitch anymore. Preloading all logos into invisible divs on every page should do the trick

Comment: It twitched because `document.location.href = '?'` caused the page to navigate. I ended solving it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cXB3a/)

Comment: It shouldn't. @Jonathan's proposal is probably a bit screwy and it's not mine. See above

Comment: Sorry I couldn't figure out how to implement your solution. I'm also not familiar with PATH_INFO nor can I find anything about it.

Comment: There's a requirement clash: either you **load** a new page and then are able to use the back button or you have a **one-page design** with the use of fragments (`#...`) and this will not be treated as "different url" by the browser and thus it's **not** reloading on `back`. Having all of both worlds isn't applicable IMHO.

Comment: Furthermore: changing the fragment currently does not fire **any** event (tested with FF 26.3), so there's no chance for correcting this with `document.onload` or `..ready`, since it's not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store history.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var history = [];

  if (!$('#ajax').length) { // Check if index.html was loaded. If not, navigate to index.html and load the hash part with ajax.
    document.location = document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
      + "#" + document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    history.push(document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  }

  if (window.location.hash) // Check if the page is being loaded with a '#'. Load the file.
    $('#ajax').load(document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1), function(){
      history.push(document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1));
   });
});

$(document).on("click", "a:not(.regular)", function (e) {
  var url = this.href;
  if (url.indexOf("https") != -1 || url.indexOf('.html') == -1) // External link or picture
    return;

  e.preventDefault();

  $('#ajax').load(url, function () {
      document.location.href = '#' + url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      history.push(url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  });
});

$(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
    $('#ajax').load(history[history.lastIndexOf(document.location.href)-1], function(){
       document.location.href =  "#" + history[history.lastIndexOf(document.location.href)-1];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as following admitted that although it works, it's likely far from the most elegant solution:

```
var lastLocation = document.location.href;

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!$('#ajax').length) { // Check if index.html was loaded. If not, navigate to index.html and load the hash part with ajax.
        document.location = document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) +
            "#" + document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    }

    if (window.location.hash) // Check if the page is being loaded with a '#'. Load the file.
        $('#ajax').load(window.location.hash.substr(1));
});

$(document).on("click", "a:not(.regular)", function (e) {
    var url = this.href;
    if (url.indexOf("https") != -1 || url.indexOf('.html') == -1) // External link or picture
        return;

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#ajax').load(url, function () {
        var pagename = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        // Keep track of last location.
        lastLocation = document.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, "") + '#' + pagename;
        document.location.href = '#' + pagename;
    });
});

window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    // Test if popstate changed while lastLocation wasn't updated.
    if (lastLocation != document.location.href)
        location.reload();
    else
        return;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate with back button `ready` event is not triggered because of [back-forward cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching). Instead [pageshow event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/pageshow) is triggered. You could force page reloading in `pageshow` event handler.

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
};
```